How to build and publish to local maven a debug version of OpenJFX?
The stock releases of OpenJFX have the debug information removed from the builds. More times than not, I find myself in the depths of FX in my debugger, but it's less useful because the information has been removed.
I have been looking at this page https://wiki.openjdk.org/display/OpenJFX/Building+OpenJFX and have downloaded and successfully built the trunk of OpenJFX on my MacOS machine, using JDK 21. And by "successfully", I mean the build seems to complete without errors. I did this by simply running "sh gradelw".
According the gradle.properties.template, the debug build is the default build. I copied the template to gradle.properties, and change the CONF setting to Release, and compared the class files. They are, indeed, smaller, which suggests the debug data is not being generated for release, helping confirm that the default build has the debug information.
On the web page, there is a long list of tasks, including publication tasks. Notably one named 'publishToMavenLocal'.
When I run 'sh gradlew tasks --all', none of the publication tasks show up.
I would like to push this build to maven, so I can change my pom file to use the debug build in order to get better information when debugging my FX projects.
How can I properly publish the build artifacts for OpenJFX to my local Maven repository?
Addenda:
"Variable information not available, source compiled without -g option". That's what I get in my IDE when I'm stepping into FX code. So, I can't view local variables in methods, just the parameters and class variables. This happens with 22.0.2.
The OpenJFX build for "release", they use -g:source,lines and for "debug", they use -g:source,lines,vars.
I simply want to deploy the debug artifacts to local .m2 Maven repo.

"The stock releases of OpenJFX have the debug information removed from the builds" -> Which builds?  What debug information?  I use the Intel Mac jars from Maven and can debug the Java code in the Idea debugger fine.  I have never tried to debug the native CPU or GPU code, that would take special tools and skill.  There are various undocumented system properties for outputting additional debug logs (such as the pulse logger). They can be enabled by setting the appropriate Java system property.  I rarely use those.

@jewelsea "Variable information not available, source compiled without -g option". That's what I get in my IDE when I'm stepping into FX code (v19 at the moment, but it's been like this for several previous versions). So, I can't view local variables in methods, just the parameters. (Same thing happens with those 22.0.2 jars you linked, I just checked). Yes, I just checked, for "release", they use -g:source,lines and for "debug", they use -g:source,lines,vars. So, the question stands.

According to What does the javac debugging information option -g:vars do? "The -g:vars option will insert a LocalVariableTable into your class file . . . You don't normally need this for debugging if you have the source available. However if you don't have the source it can be useful.".

All source is available for JavaFX as it is open source. IDEs like Idea can be configured to automatically download the sources or manually download through an Icon button in the IDE maven window. So I don't have a reason to add a -g:vars option to the build, at least in my development pipeline, yours may differ I guess.

@jewelsea Yes, I have the source code, the IDE download it, thats how I can step into it in the first place. I can even build it. For whatever reason it seems to be a limitation with NetBeans in this case to not have the vars information. I can't speak to IDEAs. I just need to get the OpenJFX build into a Maven artifact I can deploy to my local .m2 repo. to satisfy my IDEs need.

Is mvn install of any use in this?

@trashgod There is no pom.xml. This is not a maven build, so that won't work. I'll probably have to just hand craft my own fake pom and install the jars that way (or just chisel it into my repo by hand). Just seems silly since the artifacts exist somewhere.

There is a property for enabling maven publishing tasks in the JavaFX build.gradle. // Specifies whether to enable the Maven publishing tasks defineProperty("MAVEN_PUBLISH", "false") ext.IS_MAVEN_PUBLISH = Boolean.parseBoolean(MAVEN_PUBLISH).  Perhaps if you define that externally or modify the default value to true, the missing maven publishing tasks will be become available to you (I didn't try it).

Info on what defineProperty does: "If the given named property is not defined, then this method will define it with the given defaultValue. Any properties defined by this method can be substituted on the command line by using -P, or by specifying a gradle.properties file in the user home dir", so I guess gradle -PMAVEN_PUBLISH=true <somegradletask> or gradle.properties with an entry MAVEN_PUBLISH=true.

@jewelsea Yes, that's it. Thank you very much. I know ][ much about gradle, it never occurred to me that the tasks would be optional within the build script. In this case, 'sh gradlew -PMAVEN_PUBLISH=true publishToMavenLocal' published some artifacts to maven. But it does not publish the sources nor javadoc, and, for whatever reason, when I compile against the new version, the compiler can't find any of the modules (i.e. javafx.base, etc.). There's nothing obvious in the build for these (there's a javadoc task, but those aren't published it seems). But thanks!

NetBeans supports source level debugging; in this case, the goal is to target the artifacts from building OpenJFX from source. A critical element is ensuring that NetBeans has access to the relevant source artifact. Without this, NetBeans may balk or display a decompiled listing; with it, stepping in and out of code is relatively painless. While this answer isn't a complete solution, it may offer a way forward.
Maven Project
A maven project, illustrated here, is convenient in that you can right-click on the desired project dependency to download available sources. As yours are local, you may need to resort to the Apache Guide to installing 3rd party JARs.
Alternatively, consider building a Custom JDK+JavaFX Image using the artifacts as built. The resulting run-time image can be added as a distinct NetBeans platform in Tools > Java Platforms.
Ant Library Project
An ant project, illustrated here, offers the advantage of targeting the artifacts in a library, seen here. Simply add the relevant file or folder to the corresponding Classpath, Sources or Javadoc tab.
The typical SDK download includes a file named src.zip; it may appear among your build artifacts. This file is a composite of each module's Javadoc. Simply adding src.zip to the Sources tab appears to be insufficient. With reference to NetBeans URIs and URLs, you may need to edit the library's xml directly to access the archive's internal structure:
<resource>jar:file:/…/lib/javafx-sdk-21.0.4/src.zip!/javafx.base/</resource>
<resource>jar:file:/…/lib/javafx-sdk-21.0.4/src.zip!/javafx.controls/</resource>
…

The file location is platform-dependent; MacOS is shown:
~/Library/Application\ Support/NetBeans/22/\
    config/org-netbeans-api-project-libraries/Libraries/JFX.xml

Addendum: The issue with Adding JavaFX sources to Ant Library appears to be fixed in pull request #7932 and NetBeans 24.

So, my solution to this, in the end, was to just hand craft my own entries in .m2.
I went and grabbed a source release that I think matches the version I'm using (22.0.2 in this case). I then built it using sh gradlew.sh. This creates a full debug build by default. It puts all of the jars in the build/publications directory.
In publications, there's no source jar, no javadoc jar. Just code jars.
Fine.
So I then donned a caving helmet, turned the light on, and clawed my way down into the .m2/repository/org/openjfx directory.
There are all the different artifacts. Specifically for my use case, I was interested in javafx-base, javafx-graphics, and javafx-controls. Also note there's a parent javafx artifact as well.
Each of these directories contain, among others, a 22.0.2 directory. Which is the version I was using.
I went into each of those artifact directories, and created a 22x directory as a sibling to 22.0.2. I then copied the contents of the respective 22.0.2 files into the 22x directory. Now, all of these directories contained the code, javadoc, and source jars for each artifact. (Save for the javafx directory which is just a pom file, essentially.)
I then proceeded to copy the appropriate jar files out of the publications directory into their respective places, overwriting the original 22.0.2 jar files.
Next, I renamed all of the 22.0.2 files to 22x files. I then updated all of the poms to reference 22x instead of 22.0.2. Finally, I removed all of the sha1 files.
Once that was all done, I went to my project, updated my pom to 22x, rebuilt it, launched it in debug mode, stepped into JavaFX code, and, et voilà, it worked. There were my local variables.
Then, I turned off my light and took my caving helmet off.
I'd like to argue that I shouldn't have had to do all this, since the project apparently makes regular releases to maven. I'd prefer to just use their tooling, but this was expeditious.
